# How to manipulate arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with 2 spots in it(it must have 2 spots in the beginning ). i need to get user input and double the array  when user enters more than the array can hold. Also Upon entering -1 the user input should stop. The array must also not accept duplicates.

i don't know how to have the not accept duplicates and end the program when the user entters -1 while still doubling the array every time it fills up.

Here's what i have so far but its flawed and wont run properly.

```
    public class GroupArrays {

public static void main(String[] args)  {

 Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
int [] numbers   =  new int[2];
int x;
int n=0;



    for( int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter number"); 
        int number =  input.nextInt();

         while ( input.hasNextInt() )
         {
            x = input.nextInt();


            if ( n == numbers.length )
            {

               int[] h;  
               h = new int[ 2*numbers.length ]; 

               for ( int i1 = 0; i1 < numbers.length; i1++ )
               h[i1] = numbers[i1];               

               numbers = h;      

             }
          if(x == -1){
                break;
            }

             numbers[n] = x;  
             n++;        
         }

         for ( int i1 = 0; i1 < numbers.length; i1++ )
                System.out.println( numbers[i1] );
             }
          }
```

I can figure out how to do all the things individually but it becomes difficult when i have to do them all to 1 array and do user input. 
PS. I feel like i have made this more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only give you hints on how to solve the problem, and on how to write code that is easier to understand and maintain, even (and most importantly) by yourself.

Split the code in methods, doing simple tasks. Don't try to write everything as a giant piece of code.

The pseudo code of the algorithm would be

```
loop
    ask and get input number

    if (number is -1) 
        break out of the loop

    else if array already contains number
        print error message

    else 

       if no space left in array
           array = copy of array with doubled length

       store number in next available index in array and increment the next available spot index
end of loop

print the array
```

Now, you can see that there are things that can be implemented easily as  separate methods:

- ask and get input number
- check if array already contains number
- copy of array with doubled length
- print the array

Start by writing the signature of these simple methods, without implementing them. Then write the algorithm by calling these methods.

Then implement the simple methods one by one and test them one by one. You can do that, for now, by just writing a main method that calls them with hard-coded arguments, and see if they do what you expect them to do.

Once every of them is written and tested, test the main algorithm. If you made a mistake, iterate, by re-testing the methods you had to modify.

While coding all the methods, choose names that indicate clearly what the variables represent, and what the methods do, even if they're long. For example, `nextAvailableIndex` is much much clearer than `x`. Using good names helps everyone, including you, to understand the code and find bugs.

Also, indent the code strictly, as you type. The code you posted is not indented correctly, which makes it difficult to understand its structure. Stick to 4 spaces as indentation level, and always use curly braces around the body of your `if`, `for`, etc. ALways place them after the if/for, and not on the next line. Be consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should start psudocoding on paper first. i have a problem of figuring it out as i type and usually i'm wrong.

Comment: That's why it's very important to split it in small, simple parts. Those are easier to grok, implement and test. And if you messed up, they're easier to modify. Once you have good simple building blocks, assembling them becomes easier.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class GroupArrays {

 public static void main(String[] args)  {

 Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
 int [] numbers   =  new int[2];
 int x;
 int n=0;



for( int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    System.out.println("Please enter number"); 
    int number =  input.nextInt();

     while ( input.hasNextInt() )
     {
        x = input.nextInt();


        if ( n == numbers.length )
        {

           int[] h;  
           h = Arrays.copyOf[numbers,2*numbers.length ]; //change     

         }
      if(x == -1){
            break;
        }

         numbers[n] = x;  
         n++;        
     }

     for ( int i1 = 0; i1 < numbers.length; i1++ )
            System.out.println( numbers[i1] );
         }
      }
```

Use `Arrays.copyOf(array_name,array_length);` to create new arrays with varying lengths.